Is there any meaning to the extra-points introduced by a convolution product?
Mathematically speaking, when convolving a $N$-points signal with a $M$-points signal, the resulting signal contains $N+M-1$ points.
In practice, the $N$-points signal may be an audio signal to which we want to remove some frequency components, so we design a filter whose impulse response fits our desires.
Then, we convolve the $N$-points audio signal with the $M$-points impulse response of the filter, resulting in an output signal containing $N+M-1$ points, and because $N+M-1>N$, the filtered audio signal is longer than the raw audio signal.
In this case, is there any real meaning to these extra-points ? I guess that we just discard them, and keep only the $N$ first points for the output signal, is that true ?

Well, you mustn't just discard them.  Particularly when using the FFT to do fast-convolution.

Sure, the samples at the end contain the convolution of the last samples of your signal with the filter. Imagine your filter being a bit boring, having the (odd-length) impulse response
$$(\underbrace{0,0, \ldots, 0}_{(M-1)/2\text{ zeros}}, 1,\underbrace{0,0, \ldots, 0}_{(M-1)/2\text{ zeros}}).$$
Clearly, that filter will just delay your signal by $(M-1)/2$ samples. Can't cut that off if you want to preserve the original signal!
FIR filter as applied in DSP are causal, meaning that by principle, even if they passed all frequencies, the group delay delay experienced by each frequency in the signal is positive (for linear phase, i.e., symmetrical, filters, it's exactly half the filter length). So, strictly speaking, you can't cut off anything of the end, because that tail contains signal effects!
So, you get $N+M-1$ samples, but only want to keep $N$. Which one to cut off then, if not the end ones? The ones at the beginning? Not really better, because the first sample coming out of the filter (if that filter is not the non-sense toy example above) will already contain influence of the first signal sample.
There's no "right" answer here. Throwing half $M-1$ from both the beginning and end is somewhat of a golden middle ground. In practice, it doesn't matter that much in audio – ideally, there's a slow fade in and fade out, otherwise the unfiltered signal already started and ended very abruptly.
But I see where this becomes a problem: imagine you've got a music album, say, some progressive rock thing, that is nominally split into CD tracks containing songs of 10 minutes each, but the transitions between them are smooth – if you put the CD in your CD player (I know, who's got these anymore?) you don't notice where "Pseudo Silk Kimono" ends and "Kayleigh" starts. However, because you're compressing these tracks individually to, say, OPUS encoded files, your codec is letting a very relaxed low-pass filter pass over the audio to get rid of inaudible whine before compression.
Now, because the encoder only sees the tracks individually, not as whole album, at the beginning of the second track, it has no information on the last $M-1$ samples of the previous track; it needs to invent them just to give the filter a starting state.
Typically, you just internally repeat the first $M-1$ samples before the actual first sample that you filter – that way, the short-time Fourier transform over that duration is consistent. And that works pretty well for the human ear – on playback of the full album from filtered compressed files, you'll typically not notice that the encoder couldn't know how the previous track ended.

thank you for this very detailed answer. For curiosity, do you see any application where we would have to truncate the output to N samples and where the choice of these N samples is more "critical" ? I thought about a video signal, where the impact of the M-1 supplementary samples would be much more noticeable than on a audio signal as discussed

I think audio is such an example.

I see. In the example given, is the repeatition of the M-1 samples at the begin of the audio signal done because it is in some way the "optimal" method, or is it just a convention ?

As, said, it conserves the STFT.

I see, thank you
